# how to track percentage complete and average training iteration runtime in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have what I think should be a simple problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

Let's say that I have something like this

```
    with tf.Session(graph=self.training_graph) as sess:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        logger.info("initializing global variables")
        sess.run(init)
        # add the operations that distory input images according to the hyperparameters
        self._setup_meta_training_tensors()
        self._add_jpeg_decoding()
        self._add_input_distortions()
        evaluation_step, prediction = self._add_evaluation_step(
                self.train_final_tensor, self.train_ground_truth_input)
        self.merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
        self.train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(
            self.model.tensorboard_directory, 'train/'), sess.graph)
        self.validation_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(
            self.model.tensorboard_directory, 'validation/'))
        self.train_saver = tf.train.Saver()
        for step in range(self.training_steps):
            start = time.time()
            train_bottlenecks, train_ground_truth = (
                    self._get_random_distorted_bottlenecks(sess,
                        self.training_batch_size,
                        self.IMAGE_CATEGORY_TRAINING,
                        self.train_bottleneck_tensor,
                        self.train_resized_input_tensor))
            # Feed the bottlenecks and ground truth into the graph, and run a training
            # step. Capture training summaries for TensorBoard with the `merged` op.
            train_summary, _ = sess.run(
                [self.merged, self.train_step],
                feed_dict={self.train_bottleneck_input: train_bottlenecks,
                           self.train_ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})
            train_time = time.time() - start
            self.train_writer.add_summary(train_summary, step)
            is_last_step = (step + 1 == self.training_steps)
            if (step % self.eval_step_interval) == 0 or is_last_step:
                train_accuracy, cross_entropy_value = sess.run(
                    [evaluation_step, self.cross_entropy],
                    feed_dict={self.train_bottleneck_input: train_bottlenecks,
                               self.train_ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})
                validation_bottlenecks, validation_ground_truth, _ = (
                    self._get_random_bottlenecks(sess,
                                                 self.validation_batch_size,
                                                 self.IMAGE_CATEGORY_VALIDATION,
                                                 self.train_bottleneck_tensor,
                                                 self.train_resized_input_tensor))
                validation_summary, validation_accuracy = sess.run(
                    [self.merged, evaluation_step],
                    feed_dict={self.train_bottleneck_input: validation_bottlenecks,
                               self.train_ground_truth_input: validation_ground_truth})
                self.validation_writer.add_summary(validation_summary, step)
```

Now my tensorboard is tracking all sorts of variables relating to the `self.training_graph` - accuracy, cross entropy, information about the weights and what not.

All I want to do is have another graph on tensorboard that tracks the average runtime of each training step. If I time the step, (see `train_time`), how do I put these into an ever increasing array and show it in tensorboard for this graph?

The issue seems to be that these values aren't apart of my main model graph, they're different values. If I make them with a new graph that simple appends new runtimes then they don't show up in tensorboard. I could make them apart of the graph but that seems dumb.. why would my complicated ML graph have a random part that caluclates the average training iteration runtime?

Comment: Can you just look at your `global_step/sec`, which essentially tracks your progress and training speed as well. Global step here means number of batches per sec.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper library like https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX which abstracts away an annoying additional session call.